# How to change the URL of parent window with URL of Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain, postmessage

In parent page i have a link to other domain website. I want to change the URL of parent window with URL of Iframe when the link is clicked. Below is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test page</title>
</head>

<body>

 <li><a href="http://mysmallwebpage.com/" target="iframe_a">Small Page</li>

  <iframe id = "frame" src="" name="iframe_a" width = 100% height = 100% style="border:none;"></iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

Once the page is loaded in iframe the browser url should also show as           http://mysmallwebpage.com/

Comment: Should the `iframe` go away once you have loaded it's url into the parent?

Comment: So you want to redirect the entire page to whatever is in the iframe? If it is another domain, you really can not read the iframe location.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst no the iframe shoukd stay as it is. Just want the parent window url to be replaced with the frame url

Comment: @epascarello i dont want to redirect. once the frame is loaded i just want my browser URL to reflect the frame url

Comment: Not possible to change the url to another domain. That is a hacker's dream.

Comment: @epascarello and by the way i can read URL even if its cross domain just by doing this - `document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.location;`

Comment: @ConfusedMap not sure how you can do that with  same origin policy.

Comment: Imagine: User clicks link. Load fake Barclays site into iframe. Change URL to say barclays.com -- There's a reason changing the URL is not allowed!

Comment: @Stuart can we do something like window.location.replace with document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.location; using postmessage() or something?